# JSP File is having content but not showing content

Tags: java

I was working in my project using netbeans 8.02 
in JSP ,and i have faced a power cut and regaining the power my file is showing size of 192kb but on opening it I am not getting any content visible

Comment: Maybe a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space?

Comment: You have a corrupted file. Just restore it from the version saved in your version control system.

Comment: Try to open in other IDE like Notepad ++, if you are able to see data. Then delete project from netbeans and again add.